# Bedeutung von »maximal« in Ausdrücken wie »nach maximal 72 Stunden«

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adverb

Wie ist der Ausdruck *»nach maximal 72 Stunden«* in folgendem Satz zu verstehen?

> Sie können *nach maximal 72 Stunden* einen neuen Termin über unser System buchen.

*»maximal«* ist ja mit *»höchstens«* zu übersetzen. Laut meinem Sprachgefühl, das aber wohl von anderen Sprachen und der Informatik beeinflusst sein kann, wäre *»erst nach (minimal) 72 Stunden«* oder *»innerhalb von (maximal) 72 Stunden«* eindeutiger.

Handelt es sich um eine etablierte Formel in Beamtenkreisen, oder um einen Fehler, oder etwa um mangelhafte Ausbildung in der Schriftsprache meinerseits?

[Update: Nun glaube ich, dass *»spätestens ab überübermorgen«* gemeint ist, die genannte Frist ist eher eine Deckung, es ist also eine Art Beamten-Inschallah.]

Comment: Keine Sorge, dein Sprachgefühl ist in Ordnung, der Satz ist definitiv seltsam. Klingt so wie es da steht nach einem so ausfallgefährdeten System, dass die Firma sich genötigt sieht, eine Garantie abzugeben, dass man garantiert innerhalb von 72 Stunden "durchkommt"...aber das ist ja wohl (hoffentlich) nicht gemeint.

Comment: Der Satz ist so zu verstehen, daß der Verfasser Schwierigkeiten im
Umgang mit der deutschen Sprache hat. Korrekt wäre, wie schon in
der Frage angegeben, «erst nach (minimal) 72 Stunden» oder
«frühestens nach 72 Stunden» bzw.
«innerhalb von (maximal/höchstens) 72 Stunden».

Comment: Ich glaube, ich habe nun verstanden.  Die 72 Stunden sind keine Regel, sondern eine Deckung für die Tatsache daß das System nicht sehr gut läuft.  Es könnte also geschehen daß es schon früher klappt, aber es wird nicht versprochen.

Comment: @Uwe *daß der Verfasser Schwierigkeiten im Umgang mit der deutschen Sprache hat.*  Der Verfasser ist das Auswärtige Amt einer berühmten Bundesrepublik.

Comment: @A.M.Bittlingmayer: Ja, so klingt das auch. Nach Beamtendeutsch.

Comment: Vermutlich kommt man auch nur als öffentliche Behörde damit durch, ganze drei Tage Wartezeit auf die Reparatur eines Servers für eine für den Kunden zumutbare Zeit zu halten...

Comment: Das liegt dann aber nicht an der Behörde selbst, sondern an dem externen Dienstleister.

Answer (score 9):

Ohne dass man den Kontext kennt oder einen Link dorthin hat, besteht natürlich die Gefahr des Irrtums, doch ich meine, die meisten Kommentatoren oben haben sich verrannt. Das Auswärtige Amt leidet durchaus nicht an Sprachzentrumsverschwurbelung, wenn es sagt:

> Sie können nach maximal 72 Stunden einen neuen Termin über unser System buchen.

Ist es nicht naheliegend, dass schlichtweg gemeint (und eigentlich ja auch gesagt) ist:

> Sie können nach einer kurzen Wartezeit einen neuen Termin buchen. Achtung, die Wartezeit kann bis zu 72 Stunden dauern, unser System ist ein bisschen träge.

Damit ist das Wort *maximal* hier völlig richtig und kontexttypisch eingesetzt. Es gibt Quintrillionen von Meldungen mit dieser Formulierung im Internet.

Andernfalls hätten die Auswärtigen Beamten eher formuliert:

> Innerhalb der nächsten 72 Stunden können Sie einen neuen Termin buchen, später nicht mehr.

Was vielleicht geholfen hätte, Irritation zu vermeiden, wäre gewesen, drei kleine Wörtchen einzufügen und somit zu schreiben:

> Sie können nach **einer Wartezeit von** maximal 72 Stunden einen neuen Termin über unser System buchen.

Comment: Der hilfreiche Kontext war daß die neue Buchung nicht ging, und Buchungen zB in ein Paar Jahren doch gehen müssen, was die Interpretation *nur < 72h* eher ausschloß.  Deine Interpretation halte ich für richtig.  Wie wäre es dann mit *(maximal (nach x))* statt *(nach (maximal x))*?  Da liegt glaube ich der Unterschied.

Comment: Vielleicht denke ich  nicht mathematisch genug, aber bist du sicher, dass zwischen *(nach Ablauf von (maximal x Stunden))* und *(maximal (nach Ablauf von x Stunden)* ein inhaltlicher Unterschied besteht? Wenn die Stunden abgelaufen sind, sind sie abgelaufen...

Comment: Vielleicht denke ich nicht menschlich genug.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Ich meine in der Tat, denselben Unterschied zu erkennen. Bei "Sie können nach maximal 72h" bezieht sich das "maximal" eindeutig auf eine Obergrenze für die Zeitdauer, die bis zum Eintritt des beschriebenen Ereignisses (dass etwas möglich ist bzw. wird) verstreichen muss. Bei "Sie können maximal nach 72h" habe ich eher den Eindruck, das "maximal" sich auf "können" bezieht und somit angibt, welche Wartezeit man sich maximal erlauben kann.

Answer (score 4):

Dieser Satz bedeutet eigentlich:

> Sie können bereits nach wenigen Sekunden einen neuen Termin über unser System buchen. Sie können aber auch nach 10, 30 oder 50 Stunden einen neuen Termin über unser System buchen. Sogar nach 72 Stunden können Sie noch einen neuen Termin über unser System buchen. Aber dann ist Schluss. Wenn Sie länger als 72 Stunden damit warten, haben Sie Pech. Denn ab der 73. Stunde wird das nicht mehr möglich sein.

Das ließe sich aber einfacher und verständlicher wie folgt ausdrücken:

> Sie haben maximal 72 Stunden Zeit, um einen neuen Termin über unser System zu buchen.

oder

> Sie können nur innerhalb der nächsten 72 Stunden einen neuen Termin über unser System buchen.

---

Ich vermute, dass in Wahrheit aber etwas anderes gemeint ist, nämlich:

> Die Möglichkeit, neue Termine über unser System zu buchen, ist derzeit gesperrt. Diese Sperre dauert maximal 72 Stunden, erst danach können Sie einen neuen Termin über unser System buchen.

oder

> Sie müssen maximal 72 Stunden lang warten, bevor Sie einen neuen Termin über unser System buchen können.

Comment: Wenn, dann ohne "Zeit" in "...innerhalb der nächsten 72 Stunden Zeit einen neuen Termin ...".

Comment: Ich stimme der hier am Anfang genannten Bedeutung nicht zu. Das wäre nur der Fall, wenn statt *nach* das Wort *noch* dort stehen würde, oder "Sie können innerhalb von maximal 72 Stunden ...". "nach maximal 72 Stunden" gibt keine obere Zeitbegrenzung an, sondern einen Zeitpunkt, *nach dem* die genannte Aktion stattfindet.

Comment: Ich stimme Huberts Antwort insofern zu, als dass der Satz, so wie er formuliert ist, etwas anderes ausdrückt als eigentlich (mutmaßlich) gemeint ist. Dass er noch wieder anders hätte formuliert sein sollen, wenn diese falsche Bedeutung die eigentliche Intention wäre, ist davon unberührt.